# Can't change TextBox.Text from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have the following C# code in my winform application:

**FormPrincipale**

```
private void butFornitore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    FormFornitore Dialog = new FormFornitore();
    Dialog.ShowDialog();
  }
  catch(Exception excDial)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("DIALOG: " + excDial.Message);
  }
}

public void getFornitore(string Codice, string Descrizione)
{
  this.txtFornitore.Text = Descrizione;
  Fornitore = Codice;
}
```

**FormFornitore**

```
private void gridFornitori_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    var Codice = gridView2.GetFocusedDataRow()["codconto"].ToString();
    var RagSoc = gridView2.GetFocusedDataRow()["dscconto1"].ToString();
    FormPrincipale Form = new FormPrincipale();
    Form.getFornitore(Codice, RagSoc);
    this.Close();
  }
  catch(Exception excGrid)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("GRID: " + excGrid.Message);
  }
}
```

The code works (i used breakpoints to check if code was executed) but the Text property of the TextBox doesn't change. I put Modifiers TextBox property on Public, so this is ok too. I'm using Dev Express Grid Control, but i don't think this is the problem. Thank's for help.

Comment: Loot at your code carefully. You created another instance of `FormPrincipale` in your second form: `FormPrincipale Form = new FormPrincipale();` and you expect to see the result on the form which you see currently which is another instance. Instead you can pass your current form1 instance to second form and use it. Also as a better option you can get values from your second form after the dialog closed.

Comment: FormPrincipale and  From1  are the same form ?

Comment: Mhhh.. so how to access the FormPrincipale GetFornitore() function without declarating a new instance?

Comment: Instead you can pass your current form1 instance to second form and use it. Also as a better option you can get values from your second form after the dialog closed.

Comment: FormPrincipale Form = new FormPrincipale();
    Form.getFornitore(Codice, RagSoc); Form.Show(); to see you result

Comment: Thanks to all, but i found more helpful Reza's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To pass the instance of your parent form, you could do something like this:

```
class FormFornitore: Form
{
   protected FormPrincipale parent;
   FormFornitore(FormPrincipale parent)
   {
      this.parent = parent;
   }

    private void gridFornitori_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
        var Codice = gridView2.GetFocusedDataRow()["codconto"].ToString();
        var RagSoc = gridView2.GetFocusedDataRow()["dscconto1"].ToString();
        /// REMOVE THIS FormPrincipale Form = new FormPrincipale();
        parent.getFornitore(Codice, RagSoc);
        this.Close();
      }
      catch(Exception excGrid)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("GRID: " + excGrid.Message);
      }
    }
}
```

Then in your "FormPricipale" use it like this

```
private void butFornitore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
  try
  {
    FormFornitore Dialog = new FormFornitore(this); // Notice the argument
    Dialog.ShowDialog();
  }
  catch(Exception excDial)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("DIALOG: " + excDial.Message);
  }
}

public void getFornitore(string Codice, string Descrizione)
{
  this.txtFornitore.Text = Descrizione;
  Fornitore = Codice;
}
```